# Sqlite database updating a row android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing an android app, in which I need update a column in a table based on the a certain where clause.Here is the code below,

```
public void updatethekeyofweeklycolumn(String profilename, String keystemp) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Profile_keysofweekly, keystemp);

    db.update(TABLE_PROFILE_SETTINGS_FOR_WEEKLY, values,Profile_Name_for_weekly +" = "+profilename, null);
}
```

The above code is working fine with where clause as null, but its throwing a force close with the whereclause is set. Is my Query wrong?

Comment: Dude, why don't you accept the answers people give you? It's not like you're supposed to give them money ...

Comment: Dude, relax. I just now saw your answer. Thanks it works.

Comment: I have not much knowledge about the api's of stack exchange. All I do is ,vote up if the answer is useful, and accept the answers if its right. I cant accept answers which doesnt work and misguide others , even if I am not paying money right? :) .If the answer turns out right, I would surely appretiate the help. Sorry man, no acceptance for a wrong answer from my side.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to escape profilename. So you either add the single ' character:

```
db.update(TABLE_PROFILE_SETTINGS_FOR_WEEKLY, values,Profile_Name_for_weekly +" = '"+ profilename + "'", null);
```

Or, the option I would follow:

```
db.update(TABLE_PROFILE_SETTINGS_FOR_WEEKLY, values,Profile_Name_for_weekly +" = ?", new String[] {profilename});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be db.update(TABLE_PROFILE_SETTINGS_FOR_WEEKLY, values,Profile_Name_for_weekly +" = ?", new String[] {profilename}) ?

Answer (score 2):

For more general help in understanding how to update a database row, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) was actually helpful this time:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

// New value for one column
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);

// Which row to update, based on the ID
String selection = FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(rowId) };

int count = db.update(
    FeedReaderDbHelper.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
    values,
    selection,
    selectionArgs);
```

This page was also helpful: [Working with SQLite Database (CRUD operations) in Android](http://codetheory.in/working-sqlite-database-crud-operations-android/)

In my case I made a method like this:

```
public long updateTime(long rowId) {

    // get current Unix epoc time in milliseconds
    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); // helper is MyDatabaseHelper, a subclass database control class in which this updateTime method is resides
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MyDatabaseHelper.DATE_TIME, date); // (column name, new row value)
    String selection = MyDatabaseHelper.ID + " LIKE ?"; // where ID column = rowId (that is, selectionArgs)
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(rowId) };

    long id = db.update(MyDatabaseHelper.FAVORITE_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, selection,
            selectionArgs);
    db.close();
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by this one :

```
db.update("yourtable", cvalue, "Profile_Name_for_weekly="+"'"+profilename+"'", null);
```