# How to change value in SQLite database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I am learning android and building a rather big project. 
My goal is to let the user change their Email address *onClick* in the **MainActivity**, but I can't figure out how to change a value in the database.

I know it should be something along the lines:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, where, value);
```

The problem is that the database is defined in the SQLiteHandler class, but I can't figure out how to use the same "*db*" in the "*update*" code. I keep getting **Cannot resolve method 'update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])'** on the **db.update**.

I tried copying

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

to my **MainActivity**, but at this point I'm lost.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) for the registration system.

My code so far:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "email";

btnChangemail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
            HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();


            String email1 = user.get("email");

            String s1 = etChangemeil.getText().toString();


            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(user.get("email"), s1);

            String where = (user.get("email")) ;
            String[] value = { email1 }; 


            db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, where, value);
        }
    });
```

Best regards,

Dan

Comment: @RanjithKumar As I stated in my question: I keep getting "Cannot resolve method.." on the db.update.
EDIT: "Cannot resolve method 'update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])'"

Comment: have you tried calling the String any different than "where"? Perhaps a SQL specific variable could confuse the interpreter? as in ```String myString = (user.get("email")) ;```
```db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, myString, value);```

Comment: @birgit Yes, I just did, and the problem still presists.

Comment: create a separate class that extends SqliteOpenHelper & access from this class.. sample tutorial http://androidexample.com/SQLite_Database_Manipulation_Class_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=51

Comment: have you checked this example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959685/sqlite-database-updating-a-row-android

Comment: @birgit When I use "SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();" in my code, I get "Cannot resolve method 'getWritableDatabase();'

I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: @RanjithKumar I already have a SQLiteHandler in my app. Do I need to create OpenHelper too?

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation:

Convenience method for updating rows in the database.

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
```

Parameters

table   =  the table to update in
values  =  a map from column names to new column values. null is a valid value that will be translated to NULL

whereClause  = the optional WHERE clause to apply when updating. Passing null will update all rows.

whereArgs = You may include ?s in the where clause, which will be replaced by the values from whereArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

you can call this method and update the row in a table

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put("your column name", "updated email");
 String selection = "id=?";
 String[] selectionArgs = {"your row id"};
 // finally 
 db.update("your table name", values, selection,selectionArgs);
```

you said you getting getWriteableDatabase() cannot be resolved, try like this.

Create a class which extends SQLiteOpenHolper and there create methods for update delete and insert so that your Db operations are flexible enough you can call them from any where, see the link below
[Link](https://github.com/Zyg0te/call-blocker/blob/master/Call_Shield/src/com/connectutb/callshield/utils/DbHelper.java).

Comment: I keep getting "Cannot resolve method 'getWritableDatabase();" with that code.

Comment: okay do like this, create other class which extends the SqliteOpenHelper and create a method for update and put the code in to a method and pass the context to it.. wait i'll update it with my answer.

Comment: Your other method is too complicated for me.
As you can see, I already have SQLiteHandler in my application. 
I still get the "Cannot resolve method".
This is my whole application right now.
[link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Comment: its a good way to do it. try to understand it, even it take some time, it will give you lot more control.

Comment: I already have SQLiteHandler. Do I have to create Helper too?

Comment: go through this simple example. [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)